# get id in navigatorcontent

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

"Stab" is a tabnavigator, I like to access the id within navigatorcontent which is datagrid. I tried `getchildbyname` can't it can't seem to find the datagrid "nc1,nc2, etc" and return null.

```
private var pdg:String="nc";
        private function stabAdd():void {
            var dg1:DataGrid = new DataGrid();
            var cn:NavigatorContent = new NavigatorContent(); 
            stab.addElement(cn);
            cn.label = "New Tab";
            cn.name = "nct"+nu;
            cn.id = "nct"+nu;
            dg1.id = "nc"+nu;
            dg1.name = "nc"+nu;
            pdg = dg1.id;   //set this as current datagrid
            nu++;

            var columns:Array = [];
            var myDataGridColumn:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("id");
            myDataGridColumn.headerText = "ID";
            myDataGridColumn.width = 40;
            columns.push(myDataGridColumn);
            myDataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("username");
            myDataGridColumn.headerText = "Name";
            myDataGridColumn.width = 160;
            .....
            dg1.columns = columns;

            cn.addElement(dg1);
            stab.selectedIndex = stab.numChildren-1;
        }
```

Comment: I dislike `getChildByName()` - try using `container["nc1"]` etc instead.

Comment: Can I have the tutorial for "container"? It seems not known to us.

Comment: container -> **parent** of the DataGrid.

Comment: oh, sorry, I still cannot get it. Can show me the code?

Comment: the parent of datagrid is cn which is a NavigatorContent, but it only shown "contains" but not "container"

Comment: Ah sorry, I mean that you would replace **container** with whatever is holding the DataGrids. stab I think?

Comment: for "stab", the only avail API is "contains", there is no "container", not there I know in Flex 4

Answer (score 0):

Container is just my terminology for parent.. How about just add all your DataGrids to an Array. Then you can search by ID like:

```
function findDataGrid(findID:String):DataGrid
{
    var i:DataGrid;
    for each(i in array)
    {
        if(i.id == findID) return i;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is what I think of but, when I wanted to removeAll() the datagrid content it will return the ID cannot be found. I still hope I can access it by hierarchy method.